# Large Android projects - how to speed up build process?

Tags: android

I have a relatively big Android project that contains about 200-250 resources, mainly .xml layouts. This means that when I modify and save one of them, the following rebuilding process takes about 1 min, which is damn annoying on the long run.

Could you recommend any tips that help on this matter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes update to the latest Eclipse Android Plugin (ADT version 12), then go:

Window > Preferences > Android > Build > TICK 'Skip packaging and dexing until export...'

[image: Preferences]

This will stop building till you export, just like it saves, knocks a few seconds off your save time when editing XML files in a large project.

Answer (score 1):

Use ADT 12. Go to Preferences->Android->Build and check 'Skip packaging and dexing until export or launch'. Resources won't be compiled when you save, only when you run your project.

Comment: you can also disable auto build in eclipse